# Box2d freezes briefly when sending network data with Pubnub

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, lag, pubnub

I’m have small app that simulate physics (box2d) and sending network data using pub nub.(Realtime sockets framework)
The issue is, when pubnub send the data, the sprite object (which get simulated by box2d) is stopped for a little and then continue.
This happen every time data is send.
I tried to it in another thread, but it continue to happen.

Any advice?

xCode 5, cocos2d 2.1

Update: FIXED.

Disable all logging 
https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/blob/master/iOS/README.md#logging

Comment: Can you add the code that shows how you created a new Thread?

Comment: Hi Ben, (nice editing), right now it look like this: (I tried couple of things before)


 [self schedule:@selector(updateUser) interval:0.5];

 - (void)updateUser
{
    dispatch_async(q_background, ^{
        
        [PubNub sendMessage:@{@"x": @(pac.position.x), @"y" : @(pac.position.y)} toChannel:channel_1];
        
    });
}

What do you think?

Comment: In general this looks good. I haven't used Pubnub so I probably won't be much help beyond this point. Are you experiencing the problem only on the iOS Simulator or also on a device? (differences can be significant).

Comment: On the device. I sent Pubnub an email regards this issue.

Comment: Hi!  We've acknowledged the email and this should not be happening as our iOS SDK is 100% async.  Also I've forwarded this thread to our SDK team to review.

Comment: @donodare please email me at support@pubnub.com, from there, we'll ask you to attach the complete PubNub logs which will contain version and commit IDs, plus a lot of debug data that will help us help you figure this out.

Comment: Hi all, the current state is that PubNub team is supporting me. Really nice guys, so stay tuned.

Comment: I update the question with the answer. Thanks PubNub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling all logging fixes the issue! https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/tree/master/iOS#logging to see how its done. Ping us again if any issues arise!